# Is Prediction the same as Compression?

Tags: information-theory, data-compression

Just came across [this transcript](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/hAvGi9YAPZAnnjZNY/prediction-compression-transcript-1) that states:

> The principle is that prediction is the same thing as compression. And
> what that means is that whenever you have a prediction algorithm, you
> can also get a correspondingly good compression algorithm for data you
> already have, and vice versa.

Even though the article gives some examples, I would like to know some answers from this community on the question: Is Prediction the same as Compression?

Comment: See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.06960.pdf.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally, yes. Prediction can be used to compress, and compression is a form of prediction. More generally, any learned pattern can be used to compress and vice versa.

This rabbit hole goes a lot deeper, for example I'd suggest [A Tutorial Introduction to the Minimum Description Length Principle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406077.pdf) as a thorough introduction into trying to *learn and choose models* using compression.

Answer (score 2):

Prediction is a very useful part of compression.

Given a sequence of unrelated integers, you can check how they are distributed and compress them say using Hufmann or arithmetic coding.

If the integers are related, you *predict* their values as good as you can, calculate the prediction errors, and compress the prediction errors; the errors should be smaller numbers than the original ones and therefore compress to a smaller size.